# ListView Populating from the 2nd Column

Tags: excel, vba

I am populating a listview from a excel range, and the listview is populating from the 2nd column instead of the first.

Is there an option that needs checked for this?

My code is as follows:

```
Dim sh
Dim LR
Dim lC
Dim r


With LVIV
   .View = lvwReport
   .FullRowSelect = True
   .Gridlines = True
   .CheckBoxes = False

   With .ColumnHeaders
      .Clear
      '.Add , , "#", 20
      .Add , , "Language", 70
      .Add , , "Time", 70
      .Add , , "Date", 70
      .Add , , "Team", 70
      .Add , , "HO #", 70
      .Add , , "Case Worker", 80
      .Add , , "Interpreter", 80
      .Add , , "Room", 30
      .Add , , "Applicant", 70
      .Add , , "Interpreter", 70
      .Add , , "Messaged DM", 70
      .Add , , "IV Start Time", 70
      .Add , , "Status", 70

   End With



 Dim li As ListItem

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(4)
    With sh
        LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    End With
    lC = 0




For r = 2 To LR
   If Left(sh.Cells(r, 6), 10) = "04/06/2019" Then
   Set li = .ListItems.Add()
        li.ListSubItems.Add , , sh.Cells(r, 4).Value
        li.ListSubItems.Add , , sh.Cells(r, 7).Value
        li.ListSubItems.Add , , sh.Cells(r, 6).Value
        li.ListSubItems.Add , , sh.Cells(r, 13).Value
        li.ListSubItems.Add , , sh.Cells(r, 2).Value
        li.ListSubItems.Add , , sh.Cells(r, 1).Value
        li.ListSubItems.Add , , sh.Cells(r, 5).Value
        li.ListSubItems.Add , , sh.Cells(r, 23).Value
        ''
        li.ListSubItems.Add , , sh.Cells(r, 13).Value
        li.ListSubItems.Add , , sh.Cells(r, 2).Value
        li.ListSubItems.Add , , sh.Cells(r, 1).Value
        li.ListSubItems.Add , , sh.Cells(r, 5).Value
        li.ListSubItems.Add , , sh.Cells(r, 23).Value
End If
Next

End With
```

I have tried creating a new listview to get the default options, but its still the same.

Comment: It's probably the same problem as your last question `Set li = .ListItems.Add(, , sh.Cells(r, 4).Value)` will probably work. and below continue from `li.ListSubItems.Add , , sh.Cells(r, 7).Value` onwards. Right now your have populated your first column with nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on the same [link](https://10tec.com/articles/excel-vba-listview-control-examples.aspx) I shared in a [former question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457510/populating-a-listview/56458211#56458211), this should work:

```
'First bit of code....
Set li = .ListItems.Add(, , sh.Cells(r, 4).Value)
    li.ListSubItems.Add , , sh.Cells(r, 7).Value
    li.ListSubItems.Add , , sh.Cells(r, 6).Value
    li.ListSubItems.Add , , sh.Cells(r, 13).Value
    'Continue your code....
```

Comment: Thanks so much, its the curly brackets I am missing